Macro for Copying and Pasting a Range of Cells that Incrementally Changes Daily
I am trying to store revenue pace data as a snapshot of values for a specific day where the data can be used again in the future.
I have a selection of cells that are connected to my dashboard which tells me how much revenue I have. I currently go in each night and copy and paste values the applicable data so it is saved statically for comparison the next year. I'd like to automate this.
The data is stored in a table with n columns and 366 rows. On January first row 1 is copied and pasted into place. The next day, row 2. Etc. Etc.
Does anyone know how to run included macro so that the range changes dynamically? It is currently on day 1. So day 2 would be E48:BR48. Then I could set a trigger to run this every night while I sleep.
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
 
function CopyandPasteSpecial() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   spreadsheet.getRange('E47:BR47').activate();
   spreadsheet.getRange('E47:BR47').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};


Suggest you read this answer as a technique to get the day of the year: JavaScript calculate the day of the year (1 - 366) Focus on the script after "Edit:". The value of "day" will be the day of the year (tested). So then it's just a matter of modifying the range..

Consider this answer:
A comment about macros
A benefit of macros is that they require no coding experience and (when deconstructed) they can be helpful as a learning tool for scripting. OTOH, a limitation of macros is that they often include commands/instructions that are unnecessary, and they are useful only for identical/repetitive tasks.
For example, the Op's script never identifies a specific sheet; everything is done at a "spreadsheet" level.  As a one-off this is OK, but as a long-term issue it is "better" to identify the relevant sheet within the script.
About the script

get the day of the year comes directly from the "edited" answer by @Alex Turpin in JavaScript calculate the day of the year (1 - 366)

var targetRangeText = "E"+day+":BR"+day shows how the range can be constructed. The values for day comes from the "get the day of the Year" code

var targetRange = sheet.getRange(targetRangeText) identifies the targetRange. These two lines can be combined but I've expressed it like this so that the OP can appreciate the different steps involved.



function updateDailyData() { 

  // identify the sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2")

  // get the day of the year
  var now = new Date()
  var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0)
  var diff = (now - start) + ((start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000)
  var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
  var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay)
  
  // build the range as text
  var targetRangeText = "E"+day+":BR"+day
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+targetRangeText)
  
  // define the range for the sheet
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(targetRangeText)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: target range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation())

  // copy/paste the targetRange
  targetRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
}


